# Tkinter crashes when Greek accentuation key is pressed ("΄")

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, crash

I'm trying to build a simple text editor (in Python 3.9, using tkinter 8.5 and MacBook Catalina) which has already a greek text in it to be edited and saved by the user. The problem is that when I run the app and type the key for greek accentuation which is "**΄**", tkinter crashes. (Normally, when the "**΄**" is pressed nothing seems to have happened, but the key pressed after that will get an accentuation, making an "έ" instead of an "ε". This "**΄**" key, is located at the key "**;**" in the english language layout/input).

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542060/typing-greek-characters-in-tkinter), tkinter can display fine these accentuated characters when inserted from the code, as a placeholder for example, but it crashes when they are pressed from the user (again, every time the key "**΄**" is pressed).

In case that matters, the Mac is bought with a greek keyboard layout. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

*The chrash log is [here](https://pastebin.com/BY2768sz), and here is the slightly modified code copied from an online source:*

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() 
root.geometry("350x250") 
root.title("Sticky Notes") 
root.minsize(height=250, width=350) 
root.maxsize(height=250, width=350) 

# adding scrollbar 
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root) 

# packing scrollbar 
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, 
            fill=Y)

text = Text(root, 
                yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) 
text.insert(INSERT, "Γιατί δεν δέχεται τόνο;") #random greek words
text.pack(fill=BOTH)

# configuring the scrollbar 
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer maintained or supported. Try using python3.

Comment: The crash log shows you're using python 2.7, yet this code should fail on the import of `tkinter` in 2.7. You need to make sure you're running python 3.x.

Comment: @BryanOakley my python2 allows 'tkinter' because something along the way required https://pypi.org/project/future/

Comment: The code in the question does not use `future`. Please make sure that the code you post is the same code that generates the error you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, @Novel it was indeed 2.7. I run it with 3.9 though and I got the same results as before.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right! I just run the code above and edited its crash log. No it's the right one, Thanks a lot!